# Where is the uv square in blender 2.93 ? The uv squares didn't show in the Edit - Preferences lists

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, selection-tools, topology

[image]I was doing the coffee cup tutorial that made by Blender Guru.(This the link of the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIUDZZMfGNI&t=599s )

In this step (at the 9:38 of the video ), he click the Edit - Preferences - Add-ons , and finally he click the "uv squares" , and then he click the left uv map in the screen , and hit "L" key to select all . At last , he hit "N" and click "to grid the shape" in uv squares.And the left uv map's shape become square shape.

My problem is I can't find the "uv squares" in blender 2.93.I can't follow the step of the tutorial step . That makes me can't finish the next step of adding a new material on the glass coffee cup.

Could you mind teach me how to find the "uv squares" in blender 2.93❤️❤️❤️
Thank you for your teaching!!!!!!‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: If you watch the tutorial carefully, he says it's an addon that doesn't come with Blender and that the link to this addon is in the video description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H i , it seems like that you need to install Uv squares ,and download it from github
here is the link : [Uv Squares](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares)

---

also if the link goes off you can use this .blend file and save it as "uv_squares.py" and then install it
[image]

---

also idk what you want to do with this addon but i guess that you can do the same thing with " flow active quads " within blender itself without any addon

Comment: Eureka !!!! I didn't know that before !!! Thank you for your teaching and guidance!!!❤️❤️❤️